# How to stop positional light moving with camera

Tags: c++, opengl, lighting, opengl-compat

When I rotate and/or move the camera in my openGL project, it is almost as if there is a spotlight moving with it, however I have set up my gl light to be positional and given it a static position.

```
void Lighting::Display()
{
    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(0.f, yoffset, 0.f); // move to start
    glTranslatef(0.f, ceilHeight * scale[0], 0.f);
    DrawLight();

    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

    glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);
    // Match colour of sphere to diffuse colour of light
    glColor4fv(specular);
    glTranslatef(0.f, -10.0f * scale[1], 0.f);
    glutSolidSphere(5.0f * scale[0], 25, 25);

    glPopAttrib();
    glPopMatrix();
    // Re-enable lighting after light source has been drawn
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

    // Set properties GL_LIGHT0
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, specular);
    //glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION, 0.0001f);

    GLfloat pos[4] = { 0.f, 950.f, 0.f, 1.f };
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, pos);

    // enable GL_LIGHT0 with these defined properties
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
}
```

I expected to have a single source of light hanging in the centre of the scene, with light being emitted equally in all directions from its position 
however a trail of light seems to be emitted as a spotlight instead.

Here is an image showcasing the issue:

[image]

As you can see there is an odd line of light being emitted.

Comment: Since you are using legacy (non modern) OpenGL API you can use [gluLookAt](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) to move eye position instead of moving model.

Comment: The camera I am referring to moves using gluLookAt already

Comment: @zombunny This dots on the ceiling are the specular highlights, isn't it. The specular light depends on the light position, the normal vector and the viewing direction. Thspecualr highlights have to change when you change the point of view.

Comment: Ah I can see that being the issue, does this mean I will just have to live with it?

Comment: @zombunny Yes. Do you have some kind of reflecting sphere? Lit it by a point light and move around it, then you can see the natural effect which is tried to be emulated by the [Blinn–Phong reflection model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinn%E2%80%93Phong_reflection_model). Of course the effect is poor, especially at the [Gouraud shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouraud_shading) of the deprecated OpenGL fixed function light model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the light position is set by [`glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, pos)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLight.xml), then `pos` is multiplied by the current model view matrix.

The intensity of the ambient light (`Ia`), diffuse light (`Id`) and specular light (`Is`), of the [Blinn–Phong reflection model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinn%E2%80%93Phong_reflection_model) is calculated as follows:

```
N  ... norlmal vector 
L  ... light vector (from the vertex position to the light) 
V  ... view vector (from the vertex position to the eye)
sh ... shininess

H     = normalize(V + L)
NdotH = max(dot(N, H), 0.0)

Ia    = 1
Id    = max(dot(N, L), 0.0)
Is    = pow(NdotH, sh)
```

So the ambient light (`GL_AMBIENT`) is independent of any direction.

The diffuse light (`GL_DIFFUSE`) depends on the normal vector of the surface (`N`) and the direction of the incident light (`L`). It stays constant on the lit surface, independent on the point of view.

The specular light (`GL_SPECULAR`) depends on the surfaces normal vector (`N`), the light direction (`L`). and the viewing direction (`V`). This causes that the specular highlights change, when you move in the scene, because the viewing direction to the lit surfaces changes.

Further note that the light calculations in the deprecated OpenGL fixed function light model are done per vertex ([Gouraud Shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouraud_shading)). The calculated light is interpolated on the area, between the the corners of the primitives. A *modern* implementation would be to do the light calculation per fragment ([Phong shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_shading)). 
Gouraud Shading cause the spotted look of the specular highlights at the ceiling and may increase an unexpected look. Tessellating the areas in smaller peaces may improve that, but the best solution would be to switch to *modern* OpenGL write a [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader) and implement a per fragment light model for your needs.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but it does not seem to have made any visible difference

Comment: This dots on the ceiling are the specular highlights, isn't it. The specular light depends on the light position, the normal vector and the viewing direction. The specualr highlights have to change when you change the point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Your pop your matrix right before setting the lighting position. As a result your position of your light is always what you set it too. You are then multiplying everything else by your View Matrix I assume. The View matrix essentially transforms the world into the view of the camera. Essentially a camera doesn't move, the world moves around the camera. Since the light is not multiplied by this view matrix ALSO you get a light that appears to maintain a constant position relative to the camera.